# Call more than 10 numbers at once

Tags: twilio

We need to implement simultaneous GSM calls, but as stated in documentation (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number), "You can specify up to ten numbers within a  verb to dial simultaneously" which looks like a very tough limit.

Could anyone please suggest a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the REST API: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls.

A quick example would look something like this:

```
# Download the Python helper library from twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token  = "your_auth_token"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

# The following grabs a list of numbers that have sent a message to my Twilio number.
call_list = client.messages.list(to='+1415XXXXXXX')

# Then loop through all the numbers in the list and send a call from Twilio number via REST API.
for c in call_list: 
    client.calls.create(to=c.from_, from_="+1415XXXXXXX", url='YOUR_VOICE_URL')
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems like an option, but 1 call per second is also a blocker for our scenario. We need the simultaneous calls, and only one to be connected.

Comment: @IvanZverev CPS is subject of modification [upon request](http://ahoy.twilio.com/cps) which might be a workaround. Also, regarding allowing one call picker, the idea is to 1. place outbound calls with API and save their identifiers 2. When the first person answer, you can drop other calls (through the REST api).